# Open terminal in PhpStorm in current directory

Tags: terminal, ide, phpstorm

Is there a way to open the integrated terminal in PhpStorm (Windows) in the current working directory?

I recently switched from Sublime Text, which had a function where I could right-click a folder and select "Open terminal here". This was great because it saved some time when working in folders nested deeper in the project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently it's not possible.

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment; mainly first one) to get notified on progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117340
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125383
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-121701
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118543

---

Right now the best I can offer is to grab & drag desired folder and drop it at already opened terminal (at tabs space) -- it will open new tab with that folder as current path.

Comment: I just tried this approach and I think it works even more efficient then right-clicking and selecting 'open terminal here'. Also voted for the top ticket. Great!

Comment: Unfortunately, this opens a whole new terminal window(tab/instance) which in turn runs any "start up" logic which in my case redirected me from the folder dragged in. After removing that though it works beautifully. Thanks!